# Form validation after whatsapp send

Tags: wordpress, whatsapp, elementor

I have this "Share with whatsapp" button which redirect on whatsapp and allow to start a conversation with a friend sending a prewritten message. (ex: https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=ehi checkout this! https:[www.mywebsite.com/](http://www.mywebsite.com/))
What I want to achieve is that after, and only after, sending the message, the user is redirected again to my website and an hidden form become visible to insert his email and automatically receive a discount.
The tough part for me is how to validate that the person has delivered the message on whatsapp...
I'm using elementor so even a plugin solution would be fine to me.

Advanced request: how can I set a minimum amount of delivery to make appear the form? ex. after 3 messages sent

Thanks everyone!